# I'm walking in a busy street, then my flip flop suddenly breaks, what to do now?

Tags: repair, shoes

One day I'm walking down in a busy streets, this street is far from my home and I didn't bring anything on me then suddenly my flip flop breaks.

What should I do now? I know I can walk to the nearest mall but it is a shame to walk without flip flop you know?

[image: Broken flip-flop]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen my girlfriend fixing this problem with **hair elastics** which she is always carrying on her hair or in the bag.

[image: Large elastic bands]

Put this elastic around your foot and under the flip-flop

[image: Band around flip-flop]

Answer (score 7):

Go to the nearest cafe and take some cocktail tooth picks and use them to keep the strap in place.

You can do this by pushing the strap back through the hole and then pushing the cocktail sticks through the plastic bobble end bit in a cross shape. If the wooden/plastic cocktail stick is not strong enough to push through the material, use a fork to create a hole first to push the cocktail stick through.

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated that :

> **I'm walking in a busy street**, then my flip flop suddenly breaks what to do now?

You can use chewing gum if you have one and then chew it till it become little bit soft and then take it out with your hand from mouth and use it as a gum. It seems quite odd but still it will be helpful for longer time.

Answer (score 2):

I think your biggest problem will be having anything on you to fix a flip-flop with if you are just walking down the street unprepared. But from the pic you posted, the first thing that comes to mind is pushing the "post" of the flip-flop through the hole that is now too big, then wrapping it with a rubber band or a hair scrunchy on the bottom of the shoe.

Comment: Great answer, I didn't notice that.